# How to create 4 hour time interval in Time Series Analysis (python)

Tags: python-3.x, time-series

I'm totally new to Time Series Analysis and I'm trying to work on examples available online

this is what I have currently:

```
# Time based features
data = pd.read_csv('Train_SU63ISt.csv')
data['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Datetime'],format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

data['Hour'] = data['Datetime'].dt.hour 
data['minute'] = data['Datetime'].dt.minute 

data.head()


    ID             Datetime Count   Hour    Minute
0   0   2012-08-25 00:00:00     8      0         0
1   1   2012-08-25 01:00:00     2      1         0
2   2   2012-08-25 02:00:00     6      2         0
3   3   2012-08-25 03:00:00     2      3         0
4   4   2012-08-25 04:00:00     2      4         0
```

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
    ID             Datetime Count   Hour    Minute          4-Hour-window
 0   0  2012-08-25 00:00:00    20      4         0    00:00:00 - 04:00:00
 1   1  2012-08-25 04:00:00    22      8         0    04:00:00 - 08:00:00
 2   2  2012-08-25 08:00:00    18     12         0    08:00:00 - 12:00:00
 3   3  2012-08-25 12:00:00    16     16         0    12:00:00 - 16:00:00
 4   4  2012-08-25 16:00:00    18     20         0    16:00:00 - 20:00:00
 5   5  2012-08-25 20:00:00    14     24         0    20:00:00 - 00:00:00
 6   6  2012-08-25 00:00:00    20      4         0    00:00:00 - 04:00:00
 7   7  2012-08-26 04:00:00    24      8         0    04:00:00 - 08:00:00
 8   8  2012-08-26 08:00:00    20     12         0    08:00:00 - 12:00:00
 9   9  2012-08-26 12:00:00    10     16         0    12:00:00 - 16:00:00
10  10  2012-08-26 16:00:00    18     20         0    16:00:00 - 20:00:00
11  11  2012-08-26 20:00:00    14     24         0    20:00:00 - 00:00:00
```

Comment: The idea is, get the hour number, divide by 4, round down, then multiply by 4 for the 4 hour window, then groupby that column sum

Comment: Or using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49484023/pandas-dataframe-grouping-by-timestamp

Comment: your idea gives me a value of 4 through all the columns in the above dataframe which is not what I want.

Comment: What do you mean give you a value of 4 through all columns?

Comment: ID Count Hour minute
Datetime    
2012-08-25 00:00:00 4 4 4 4
2012-08-25 04:00:00 4 4 4 4
2012-08-25 08:00:00 4 4 4 4
2012-08-25 12:00:00 4 4 4 4
2012-08-25 16:00:00 4 4 4 4

Comment: I believe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480503/how-to-divide-a-given-time-series-dataset-into-4-hour-window-in-r is something that I would want to have in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the resample function, see here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
sampled_data = data.resample(
    '4H',
    kind='timestamp',
    on='Datetime',
    label='left'
).sum()
```

The function is very similar to groupby and groups the data into chunks of the column specified in `on=`, in this case we use timestamps and chunks of 4 hours.
Finally, you need to use some kind of disaggregation, in this case `sum()`, to convert all elements of each group into a single element per timechunk